# Vectorize a function so that it can run on multiple rows of n-dimensional arrays simultaneously?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a function F(x,[y]), that applies a set of parameters [y] to a large dataset x.  To find the maximum value of F across different sets of [y]'s, I have another function MaxVal(F,i) where i is a set of n [y]'s. MaxVal returns the [y] with the greatest F.

Because both the data set x and the parameter set i are so large, iteration across i would be very slow. Is there a way to vectorize MaxVal so that F begins to run on multiple sets of [y] simultaneously?

I don't think that F itself can be vectorize because each iteration is dependent on a result from a previous iteration.

I am new to python, but my understanding is that np.vectorize would still be an optimized iteration rather than true vectorization. Given the size of the dataset and the large number of [y], this may still be quite slow.

Comment: Did you try `np.vectorize`? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html

Comment: `np.vectorize` will not do any magic; you should not expect it to work any faster than well-thought-out loops. If you are new to Python, you should perhaps not dismiss a truly vectorized solution to your problem; nobody can help with that without seeing what it does.

Comment: @rdas they mentioned it explicitly in their question...

Comment: In `numpy` `vectorize` (in the true sense) means using the builtin `numpy` operators and functions to perform calculations in fast compiled code.  Nothing is 'simultaneous', it just moves the iteration from slow Python code to faster C code.  The programmer has to think in terms of operating on the whole array(s) at once, because (most of) the iteration details are out of his control.  `np.vectorize` imitates this process, but in slower Python code.